# Stability plot of upward difference implicit time

Tags: pde, finite-difference, stability, advection

I am analyzing the stability of 1D convection (advection) equation as shown in the picture. When I derive the equations as shown I want to get rid of the complex number.
[image: Trial of equations derivation]
I`m asking if those stability plots make sense or not
[image: Stability plot for various courant numbers from 0.25 to 1]
[image: Basic info of stability plots]

I want to get rid of a complex number

Comment: Can you please type your equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: ok, sure, but I`m asking about the graphs, is it correct that as the wave numbers increase the amplification factor goes far from One?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to compute the magnitude of $\gamma$ and then consider the maximum/minimum value of your trigonometric functions.